# Powershell - list found and not found strings during search

Tags: string, powershell, search

I have a script that will search for strings or a list of strings and create a report.  What I'm having trouble with is, I now need to know what strings were NOT found as well as those that were.  Would anyone be able to offer an alteration to the script below to achieve this?

Thanks,
-Ron

```
$searchWords=Get-Content "C:\Directory containing file\Text_To_Search_For.txt"

# List the starting(parrent) Directory here - the script will search thropugh every file and every sub-directory - starting fromn the one listed below  
Get-Childitem -Path "C:\Start my search here\" -Recurse | 
  Select-String -Pattern $searchWords | 

# the output will contain the [Found] word, the document it found it in and the line contents/line number containing the found string 
    Select Filename,Line,@{n='SearchWord';e={$_.Pattern}}, LineNumber
```

Comment: would help if you could provide what the expected result should look like.

Comment: What you are after is shown as examples in the PowerShell help files. There are many examples already here on Stackoverflow and all over the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [common `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) to capture all matches output by [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string), which allows you to analyze all matches after the fact, via [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object):

```bash
# Note the `-OutVariable allMatches` part, which records Select-String's
# output objects in self-chosen variable $allMatches.
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Start my search here" -Recurse | 
  Select-String -OutVariable allMatches -Pattern $searchWords | 
  Select-Object Filename,Line,@{n='SearchWord';e={$_.Pattern}}, LineNumber

# Get the array of distinct words (patterns) that matched.
$wordsWithMatches = $allMatches.Pattern | Select-Object -Unique

# Now output those that *didn't* match.
Compare-Object $searchWords $wordsWithMatches -PassThru
```

Comment: Thank you!  I just ran the script - perfect!

Comment: I know this sounds nitpicky as the script is performing well.  Is it possible to have the output include a label?  Such as "String not found ==> ".  Instead of just outputting the string.  Makes the report creation easier.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @user3166462. You could do something like `Compare-Object $searchWords $wordsWithMatches -PassThru | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{ Result = 'String not found ==>'; String = $_ }
}`, or you could construct custom objects whose properties match those of the `Select-Object` call, where you put `String not found ==> ` in the `Line` property.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2

```
Get-Help -Name Select-String -Examples
```

A quick example from the guidance in the help files. You of course can tweak as you need to.

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' | 
ForEach-Object {
    IF  (Select-String -Path $PSItem.FullName -Pattern 'test')
    {"Target word found in filename " + $PSItem.FullName}
    Else {'Word not found'}
}


# Results
<#
...
Word not found
Word not found
Word not found
Target word found in filename D:\Temp\UserData.csv
Word not found
Target word found in filename D:\Temp\UsersList.csv
Target word found in filename D:\Temp\Using Inner classes in C#.txt
Target word found in filename D:\Temp\VerboseLogFile.log
Word not found
Word not found
Word not found
...
#>
```

This can be tweaked to get the lines in the file where the pattern is found vs just the filename as well.

Comment: Thank you!  That link is now bookmarked!

Comment: No worries, and I see you've selected 'mklement0', which is solid, but as always in code, multiple ways of addressing a given task are always possible.